# How to crop and rescale PDF pages?

Tags: pdf, edit

To enhance the reading experience on e-readers, I'd like to edit PDF to 1) remove the margins and 2) increase the size of the content.

I like MuPDF's [mutool](https://mupdf.com/docs/) and John Whitington's [cpdf](https://community.coherentpdf.com/) because they're available for Windows, and don't require Java or .Net.

Apparently, MuPDF's mutool can't do this; cpdf can crop pages but I didn't find if it can increase the text size.

Do you know how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: From my ignorant perspective, this sounds like a major pain in the butt. Maybe it might be doable with some knowledge about how PDFs work though.

Comment: I don't know much about PDF either, having just read John Whitington's "PDF Explained" and Sid Steward's "PDF Hacks". But since PDF is dynamic, I assume it's possible to tell it to change the size of the text of a given page.